# VBScript - How do I get these workbooks to talk?

Tags: vba, vbscript, excel

I posted earlier about getting my VBScript to wait until a process had finished before continuing (further info: [VBScript - How to make program wait until process has finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279404/vbscript-how-to-make-program-wait-until-process-has-finished).

I was given an adequate answer after some discussion. However, it seems that I am now going in a new direction with the code as the solution presented another problem that I am hoping you may be able to help me with.

Basically I have some code which I have provided below. It takes in 4 arguments, one of which is a PATH to a folder containing many files which I want to use along with the other three in my VBA macro.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 4 Then

    ' process input argument
    Set args = WScript.Arguments
    arg1 = args.Item(0)
    arg2 = args.Item(1)
    arg3 = args.Item(2)
    arg4 = args.Item(3)

    ' Create a WshShell instance 
    Dim WShell
    Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    ' Create an Excel instance
    Dim x1
    Set x1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Disable Excel UI elements
    x1.DisplayAlerts = False
    x1.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    'x1.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    x1.FeatureInstall = msoFeatureInstallNone

    ' Open the Workbooks specified on the command-line
    Dim x1WB 
    Dim x2WB 
    Dim x3WB 
    Dim x4WB 
    Dim strWB1
    Dim strWB2
    Dim strWB3
    Dim strWB4

    Dim FSO
    Dim FLD
    Dim FIL
    Dim strFolder

    strWB1 = arg1
    Set x1WB = x1.Workbooks.Open(strWB1)
    ' Show the workbook/Excel program interface. Comment out for silent running.
    x1WB.Application.Visible = True

    strWB2 = arg2
    Set x2WB = x1.Workbooks.Open(strWB2)
    ' Show the workbook/Excel program interface. Comment out for silent running.
    x2WB.Application.Visible = True

    strWB3 = arg3
    Set x3WB = x1.Workbooks.Open(strWB3)
    ' Show the workbook/Excel program interface. Comment out for silent running.
    x3WB.Application.Visible = True

    'To hold the string of the PATH to the multiple files
    strFolder = arg4

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get a reference to the folder I want to search
    set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

    Dim strMyMacro
    strMyMacro = "my_excel_sheet_with_vba_module.xlsm!Sheet1.my_vba_macro"

    'loop through the folder and get the file names
    For Each Fil In FLD.Files

        WshShell.run """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe"" " & Fil, 1, true

        x1.Run strMyMacro

        '~~> Problem - How do I get the macro to run before opening the above file but run after it has opened (due to setting the bWaitOnReturn to true)
        '~~> Problem - How do I get the file on current iteration to close after the macro has completed?
        '~~> Problem - If this is not the issue, can you identify it?

    Next

    x1WB.close
    x2WB.close
    x3WB.close
    'x4WB.close

    ' Clean up and shut down
    Set x1WB = Nothing
    Set x2WB = Nothing
    Set x3WB = Nothing
    Set x4WB = Nothing

    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set FLD = Nothing

    x1.Quit
    Set x1 = Nothing
    Set WshShell = Nothing

    WScript.Quit 0

Else
        WScript.Quit 1

End If
```

The script works like this:

1. 4 arguments are passed to the script. The 3rd argument is a **.xlsm** file which contains my VBA macro. The last argument is a PATH to a folder containing multiple files.
2. It then opens up the first three Excel files.
3. Then I run a loop to iterate through the files `Fil` in the folder that was specified as the 4th argument. AFAIK this has to be done via a `WScript.shell` using the `.run` method so that the rest of the script will hang until the Excel file it is processing finishes before closing it and opening up the next file in the folder.
4. After opening up file `Fil`, I then run the macro (albeit at this moment in time unsuccessfully).

I was tempted to simply open up all of the Excel files using the `WScript.shell` object however AFAIK I would not be able to run the macro this way.

Hopefully I have been able to define my aims of this piece of VBScript though if I haven't let me know and I shall clarify. Can you help?

Thanks,
QF.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to use `x1.Workbooks.Open(Fil)` then use Shell? It would be much easier overall if you moved most of this code into a VB macro in your xlsm, and just passed the vbscript arguments to it (you can pass arguments using Application.Run). That makes the whole thing simpler to manage.

Comment: Thanks. But I require this as a VBScript since it goes along with a HTA front-end to process the files. Plus, if this was in the VBA then it would mean manually opening up each file and running the macro from Excel then closing and doing for 20+ files that I have. The point is to automate that. So I'm stuck with this really. Any other ideas? Besides, if I was to do `x1.run` I cannot provide the argument to tell it to wait can I?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any reason not to move the directory looping into your xlsm as a separate macro: your vbscript then just passes the four arguments to that macro.  It's easier to manage to loop from within Excel than from outside.

Comment: @qwerty_face, i feel Tim is right, i would use vbscript as the startpoint, not HTA, you could use a fileselector or an IE object to get your variables, then use VBA to do the Excel stuff. Since you can mix the vbscript and VBA this should not be a problem. No need for macro's also, they can be incorporatred in the vbscript/vba code.

Comment: OK Tim... So if I move most of this code into the VBA code on my **.xlsm** file, I can still use the VBScript to get the variables I require, i.e. 3 file strings and 1 folder path? Then I pass these variables from the VBScript to the VBA macro - yes? What sections of code do you suggest I place in the VBA?
@peter: can you point me to some resources where I can learn about this 'IE object fileselector'? You also say: "No need for macro's, they can be incorporatred in the vbscript/vba code." Just to ensure we're on the same page I am probably using the term "macro" when I mean my VBA code.

Comment: about the filebrowser in vbscript, can't mix it in here, ask in a separate question please, about the macro, i mean you can place all your VBA code in the .vbs itself, no need to place it in the .xlsm as VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines might work for you (in Excel).  A few things I'm not clear on though:

1. Where is your existing VBA macro - I'm guessing it's in one of the 3 files you're opening?
2. What types of files are in the folder you're looping through? I guessed Excel.
3. How is the vbscript being run?  It looks like you're shelling out from your HTA, but why not include it directly in the HTA?  That would save you from having to shell out and pass arguments...

`Option Explicit`

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Sub ProcessFolder(path1, path2, sFolder)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim s

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(path1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(path2)
    If Right(sFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sFolder = sFolder & "\"

    s = Dir(sFolder & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

    Do While Len(s) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & s)
        ProcessFile wb
        wb.Close False
        s = Dir()
    Loop

    wb1.Close False
    wb2.Close False

End Sub


Sub YourExistingMacro(wb As Workbook)
'do stuff with wb and presumably the other 3 open files...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. What I have since done is scrap the HTA and VBScript and include the file and folder selectors within the VBA so this problem is now resolved. But to retrospectively answer your questions: 1. VBA macro is in the **.xlsm** file which is one of the first 3 files opened, 2. Yes, all files in folder are either **.xls** or **.xlsx**, 3. The VBScript is being called from the HTA where the HTA accepts 3 files and 1 folder path and passes those as arguments to the VBScript - so yes, I was shelling from the HTA. That said - your code is useful.