# running c# console application from excel and wait for app to finish

Tags: c#, .net, vba, excel

I am running a c# console application from within Excel using the line of code below. The code is working fine. The process takes about 20 seconds to run. I was wondering how I get my vba code to wait for the c# application to finish before continuing execution of the code following this line?

I do not want to use a pause or similar function.

```
 Dim id As Integer
 id=Shell("""C:\MyFolder\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe"" /PARA1 " & p1 & " /PARA2 " & p2, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Look at this question [excel-vba-wait-for-shell-command-to-complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/excel-vba-wait-for-shell-command-to-complete)

Comment: Take a look at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279404/vbscript-how-to-make-program-wait-until-process-has-finished

Comment: thanks guys - both work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this code (inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells)):

```
Dim id As Integer
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

id = wsh.Run("""C:\MyFolder\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe"" /PARA1 " & p1 & " /PARA2 " & p2, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```