# Run a cmd.exe which calls a bat file and wait to finish

Tags: vbscript, win32-process

I need to be able to run cmd.exe with special privilege to run a bat file and wait until it finishes.

I already managed to open cmd.exe with special privilege but I cannot find a wait until the bat file finishes.
I cannot use `WScript.Shell` because `cmd.exe` is opened with special privilege using cimv2.

```
Dim WMIObj, strHost, intProcessID

On Error Resume Next

strHost = "."

Set WMIObj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strHost & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
If IsObject(WMIObj) Then
    WMIObj.Security_.Privileges.AddAsString "SeRestorePrivilege", True
    WMIObj.Create "cmd.exe /c cd /d c:\temp && asd.cmd && pause", Null, Null, intProcessID
End If

Set WMIObj = Nothing
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26588562/4473405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a loop to wait until the process with PID `intProcessID` disappears:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
  Set p = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM W32_Process WHERE ProcessID=" & intProcessID)
Until p.Count = 0
```