# JavaScript & HTA: Installing an application and waiting for it to finish installing before moving to next function

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm new to HTA development and JavaScript.  I have created a function which will launch a setup.exe when the Install button is clicked and starts a timer as well.  I would like for the script to wait for the setup.exe process to complete before moving to the next function.  How can this be achieved?

I've been reading about callbacks but I'm thinking that it won't wait for the setup.exe to complete.  It will only launch the setup.exe and see that as meeting the criteria for moving to the next function.

Any direction on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

-Adam

Comment: It would be good to show the code you have and your attempt with a callback function.

Comment: No callback code yet.  I'm going to try using callbacks today.  I was only reading about them yesterday.  My guess is that it will launch setup.exe but not wait for the process to finish...what are your thoughts based on how callbacks work (without posted code)?

Comment: Okay so callbacks did not work for me.  I tried following examples that I found online but the setup.exe would launch and then continue.  To resolve this, I used vbscript and used the code from the following right answer example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279404/vbscript-how-to-make-program-wait-until-process-has-finished - it waited for the program to finish before moving to my next java script function.  Be sure to change set oShell = WScript.CreateObject to set oShell = CreateObject or you will get an error